# Applying Styling to :before Element Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add styling to a before: element dynamically.

On my page, I have the following container

```
<p class="stepNode 203"></p>
```

I dynamically added styling to the page to set a background image to this element:

```
  $('head').append('<style> .stepNode.'+node_id+':before {background: url("'+$(divs[k]).data('image')+'");}</style>');
```

produces:

```
<style>
 .stepNode.203:before {background: url("http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/04/Puppy_2.jpg");}
</style>
```

But upon inspecting the element, this styling is never applied.

Notably, when I change the style to exclude the numerical class, the background is applied properly:

```
<style>
 .stepNode:before {background: url("http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/04/Puppy_2.jpg");}
</style>
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem?  Do I need to do anything to reapply a style if it's added dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

203 is not valid css class name,

> class names should start with a letter
>
> All CSS syntax is case-insensitive within the ASCII range (i.e., [a-z]
>   and [A-Z] are equivalent), except for parts that are not under the
>   control of CSS. For example, the case-sensitivity of values of the
>   HTML attributes "id" and "class", of font names, and of URIs lies
>   outside the scope of this specification. Note in particular that
>   element names are case-insensitive in HTML, but case-sensitive in XML.
>
> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

refer http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters

,
try changing it to `stepNode-203` or `stepNode_203` like that.

Answer (score 3):

CSS class names must not start with a digit. The classes `203` and `-203` are invalid, but `_203` is a valid alternative.

---

Quoting from [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters):

> In CSS, *identifiers* (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); **they cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen
>   followed by a digit.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can't have classes that are integers!  I changed my class name to step_203 instead of 203, and I was able to get my code to work.